# Can a cell equal the last time/date the workbook was modified?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking to see if there is a function that can equal the last time/date an Excel Workbook was modified.

I know that in Windows Explorer you can have a column to show you "Date Modified", but I am creating a large, shared workbook and would like to have that value in the workbook itself.

I am looking for the cell to auto-update anytime a change is made anywhere in the workbook (not just a particular cell). `=today()` and `=now()` are not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a VBA script like

```
Public Function LastModification()
    LastModification= Format(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "yyyy-MM-dd")
End Function
```

and then enter `=LastModification()` into the cell.

The downside of this is that you have to save the file as `.xslm` and anyone else receiving your file will need to enable macros.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, the file is already a .`xlsm` so this will not be an issue.